# Accidentally pushed an existing branch with no changes, now Bitbucket won't let me create a pull request or undo

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I’m new to SourceTree and Bitbucket. I accidentally pushed an existing branch with no changes and when I went to create the pull request in Bitbucket I got the message “Branch "master" is already up-to-date with branch…” At this point I recognized my mistake; but now Bitbucket is still showing this existing branch with the button to create a pull request under the “Your work” section and it won't let me create the pull request since there are no changes. How do I clear this from Bitbucket?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just delete the branch. Can you clarify why you want to clear the branch?

Comment: Thanks, that would be a simple solution. But I had hoped there was another fix that might help me to preserve the record of the changes on that branch.

Comment: Deleting the branch on the remote (in BitBucket) won't remove it from your local (unless you have something else that does that for you). So, you should be safe to delete the branch from BitBucket, and then just re-push it from your local whenever you're ready

Comment: I just deleted the branch in Bitbucket, then pushed my local branch, but it gave me the same “Branch "master" is already up-to-date with branch…” message when I tried to create the pull request in Bitbucket.

Comment: Pull means if there is something added or changed in the branch B and want to apply those changes into the branch A, then you can do the pull request from B to A. Since you push your changes into the master branch and it is now up to date, I guess there is no things to make pull request.

Comment: There are many different things you could do to resolve this, depending on your desired end state. What is your desired end state?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just deleting the branch and creating a new one.